# Transpose row into columns with If statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to transpose certain row values into columns.  Below is what my table looks like:

```
ID  Item        Color   Quantity
1   Shoe        Red 
1   Shirt                3
1   Hat         Black   
1   Socks                2
1   Pants       Red
```

What I want the table to look like is this:

```
ID  Shoe    Shirt   Hat    Socks    Pants
1   Red     3       Black   2       Red
```

Below is the code I am using:

```
select Max(Case When [Item] = 'Shoe' Then Color End) as Shoe
    ,Max(Case When [Item] = 'Shirt' Then Quantity End) as Shirt
    ,Max(Case When [Item] = 'Hat' Then Color End) as Hat
    ,Max(Case When [Item] = 'Socks' Then Quantity End) as Socks
    ,Max(Case When [Item] = 'Pants' Then Color End) as Pants
From Inventory
```

The problem with my code is sometimes the value for the row is in column Color and other times it's in column Quantity.  I would like to be able to use only to column with a value.  My real select statement has over 50 Max(Case) statements, so if there is someway I can do an overarching if statement and not have to do one for each line that would be great!

Comment: How do you know which column the "correct" value is in? Is the other column NULL? Then you can simply use coalesce(Color, Quantity) or isnull(Color, Quantity).

Comment: And there is never a case where both `Color` and `Quantity` have a value?

Comment: so they are never null, but Color would be blank ("") or Quantity would be 0.  And no, there can never be a value in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a **dynamic** version.

In the sub-query below, you'll notice that we use `CONCAT()`, which will handle `NULL` values appropriately.

```
Declare @Filter varchar(100) = 'Shoe,Socks'

Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = 'Select ID,' + '['+Replace(@Filter,',','],[')+']' + ' 
                From (
                       Select ID
                             ,Item
                             ,Value = concat(NullIf(Color,''''),NullIf(Quantity,0))
                       From  Inventory
                       Where charindex('',''+Item+'','','','+@Filter+','')>0
                     ) A
                Pivot (max(Value) For Item in (' + '['+Replace(@Filter,',','],[')+']' + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

> **EDIT:**

Added `NullIf()` to the `concat()` to trap "empty" values.

Comment: How would I change this so that I can select which item's I want to pivot.  So in my example what if I only wanted Shoes and Socks for example?

Comment: @VBA_SQL_Programmer Remove the Select Distinct ... not necessary because you are applying a filter

Comment: @VBA_SQL_Programmer Happy it helped

Answer (score 2):

How about using a common table expression (CTE) to find the non null value column then `PIVOT` on the Item if you know all of your Items up front. It should be noted that this only works if the other value is null, otherwise you would need to check for '' or 0.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ID, Item, COALESCE(Color, CAST(Quantity AS VARCHAR(10))) AS Value
    FROM Inventory
)
select * from CTE
pivot (max (Value) for Item in ([Shoe],[Shirt],[Hat],[Socks],[Pants])) AS c
```

Comment: So how would I check for the "" or 0?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a dictionary which maps an item to a value column. For example

```
select Max(Case When [Item] = 'Shoe' Then 
           Case col when 'Color' then Color else Quantity End 
           End) as Shoe
    ,Max(Case When [Item] = 'Shirt' Then  
           Case col when 'Color' then Color else Quantity End 
           End) as Shirt
    ,Max(Case When [Item] = 'Hat' Then 
           Case col when 'Color' then Color else Quantity End 
           End) as Hat
    ,Max(Case When [Item] = 'Socks' Then 
           Case col when 'Color' then Color else Quantity End 
           End) as Socks
    ,Max(Case When [Item] = 'Pants' Then 
           Case col when 'Color' then Color else Quantity End
           End) as Pants
From (
    select i.*, col
    from Inventory i
    join (
        values ('Shoe', 'Color') 
        ,('Shirt', 'Quantity')
        ,('Hat', 'Color')
        ,('Socks', 'Quantity')
        ,('Pants', 'Color')
        ) dict (itm, col) on dict.itm=t.item
) t
```